# How to use regex in PostgreSQL to put one point every 2 char?

Tags: regex, postgresql

How can I replace a string by putting a dot every two characters using the regexp_replace function?

For example:

1 => 1

12 => 12

123 => 12.3

1234 => 12.34

12345 => 12.34.5

123456 => 12.34.56

... and so on.

I tried some odds but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match `(.{2})(?!$)` globally and replace it with `$1.`.

The `(?!$)` part is a negative look ahead preventing a match on the last two numbers. It avoids `12.34` from being `12.34.`.

```
test=> select regexp_replace('12345678', '(.{2})(?!$)', '\1.', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 12.34.56.78
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3hDw4a/2)

Comment: And how do I apply it in the regexp_replace function?

I Tried:
SELECT regexp_replace ('12345678', '(2)', '\ 1.')

... but the result is:
12.345678

Comment: @PolianoMartini `regexp_replace('12345678', '(.{2})(?!$)', '\1.', 'g');`

Comment: If I use six character still have point in the last. 
123456 => 12.34.56. 
Oh...I have solve the problem, I have space in the last. So I use trim to clear the space.